# AWS lambda VPC cannot reach internet with IG attached

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, vpn, vpc

I have an AWS lambda function that makes a request to the internet. When it makes the request with NO VPC, it's ok, but when I add it to the VPC, it stops working. I've attached an Internet Gateway to the VPC and created a NAT Gateway with RT to use outbound 0.0.0.0/0, but it stills not working.
With the 15seconds timeout, it's always throwing TO.

Could you please help me?

I've already followed these sites:

- https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7
- http://derpturkey.com/lambda-vpc-and-internet-access-configuration/

Everything seems to be well configured.

---

[Lambda configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ecxwu.png)

[Route Table configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vahKI.png)

[IGW attached to VPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKjmD.png)

Comment: Did you follow steps mentioned in AWS documentation? - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

Comment: Yes. I've followed every step. I've tried with private subnet with NAT attached and also with public subnet with IGW attached.

Comment: I've created a dummy lambda function to request HTTP google.com, with NO VPC, it works. With the VPC it doesn't work.

Comment: You should be able to test your Lambda function from the aws lambda console test. And verify what log messages are produced. Adding Lambda to the VPC would require AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole

Comment: Same problem, AWS it's so bureaucratic :(

Comment: @Nahuel - What was the final resolution on this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to grant Internet access to an AWS Lambda function:

- Do not assign it a VPC, *or*
- Assign it to a VPC and attach an Elastic IP Address to the ENI (Elastic Network Interface) that is created in the VPC, *or*
- Assign it to a *private subnet* in a VPC and use a NAT Gateway to grant the private subnet access to the Internet

Comment: 1) I need to use VPC to reach Redis in the same subnet.
2) The VPC has an EIP attached.
3) The VPC has Internet Gateway (with the EIP) attached, and the subnet used by Lambad has a NAT Gateway with 0.0.0.0/0 outbound. 

Everything is ok, I really don't know what's going on here.

Comment: A VPC does not have an EIP — rather, a network interface _within_ the VPC is assigned the EIP. Tell me more about the subnet with the Lambda attached -- how exactly is the Route Table configured? Also, what is the route table configuration for the subnet with the NAT Gateway? Can the Lambda function connect to Redis? If not, what is the configuration of the Redis Security Group? (Feel free to Edit your question and add the details.)

Comment: I've created a dummy lambda function to request HTTP google.com, with NO VPC, it works. With the VPC it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nahuel you need a NAT Gateway.

Comment: I have a NAT gateway. Please check the images I ve posted

Comment: Can you confirm that `rtb-...22` is associated with subnet `172.31.0.0/20`? And what is the Route Table configuration for the subnet containing the NAT Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

If you have already verified the network configurtions like VPC setup, Subnets, Route Table, IG/NAG gate way. And associated the Lambda with current subnet and security groups.

Then the last thing to verify would be:

For Lambda functions to work into custom or User Defined VPC, Adding Lambda to the VPC would require AWSLambdaVPCAccessExecutionRole in addition to AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole.

Ensure that the associated role has the above permissions.

Source:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds-create-iam-role.html